# Oracle connection issue using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oracle

I'm having an issue in the `using` statement. Error is posted below. What do you guys think makes the program generate that error?

```
public JsonResult Save_Record(UserModels model)
{
    using (var con = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBEntities"].ConnectionString))    
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Here's the error in the `using` line:

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Oracle.DataAccess.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: 'metadata' is an invalid connection string attribute
```

Comment: i think there is something wrong with your `connection string`.. please see [this link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/nipuntomar/connection-strings-for-oracle/) for more details about connection strings for Oracle.

Comment: Most likely you use Entify Framework connection string not Oracle connection string.